# Where do I find information about Templates for Create Document

Tags: nautilus, shortcuts

If I right click on the desktop in Unity the context menu has 'Create Document'.

Selecting this, I get the options 'No templates installed' and 'Empty File'.

[image: Empty]

What kind of templates can I install and where do I put them - or where can I get more information on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up **Open/Libre Office** and create a blank document and save it in your **Templates** folder which is located in your Home directory (`/home/userName/templates`, where `userName` is your actual Ubuntu username)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's a pity there is no good 'help' for Unity.

Comment: Should be in the official release on the 28th http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/267972